# How to Create matrix of dynamic arrays into one array?

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm, matrix

I have dynamic number of arrays like:

```
    $a= [ 1, 2 ];
    $b= [ 3, 4, 5 ];
    $c= [ 6 ];
```

I want to merge every number from each row with parent values sustaining till all child values complete. So starting from lowest level, the matrix gets created as follows:

**Third level:**

```
[ 6 ]
```

**Second level:**

```
[ 
   [3 , 6] , 
   [4 , 6] , 
   [5 , 6]
]
```

**First/Top level(final level):**

```
[
  [1,  3,  6] , 
  [1,  4 , 6] ,
  [1,  5 , 6] ,
  [2,  3,  6] , 
  [2,  4 , 6] , 
  [2,  5 , 6]
]
```

**Note:** The number of arrays can vary and the number of elements in each array might also change.
I want a way to get those into matrix like above in the final result. Any ideas on how to get started?

Comment: Can you explain further where the numbers come from when constructing your desired output array? Also, what code have you tried so far?

Comment: i've tried to use loops to append but it got really complicated

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes Was unclear to me too. It's actually every number from each row with parent values sustaining till all child values complete.

Comment: I want exchange arrays elements in one array  of array

Comment: @vivek_23 i've used your explanation to update question.

Comment: @ShenoudaShehata I have edited your post to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks a lot @vivek_23

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before , here what tried.

**1-You can use crossJoin helper with collection**

```
$results=collect($a)->crossJoin($b,$c);
```

**2-You can use some thing native like this**

```
 function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
            if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
                return array();
            }
            if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
                return $arrays[$i];
            }

            // get combinations from subsequent arrays
            $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

            $result = array();

            // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
            foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
                foreach ($tmp as $t) {
                    $result[] = is_array($t) ?
                        array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                        array($v, $t);
                }
            }

            return $result;
        }

        dd(
            combinations(
                array(
                    array('1','2','3'),
                    array('4','5','6'),
                    array('7','8')
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks man that's saved my day i tried your code and it worked perfectly.